# Android layouts - Most efficent way to achieve what i'm after

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've been doing a bit of searching around for ways to achieve what i'm after but haven't been able to find much.

Basically i'm going to use this as a "home" screen.

I'm unable to post images but i've done a mockup in an image editor

[image: Image screenshot]

Any help would be great!

Comment: http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/

Comment: You may try using `GridLayout` with each View in the grid containing `TextView` and `Image`

Comment: You can even use a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. It's efficient enough for your condition.

Comment: Check this http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/custom-grid-view-in-android/ I used image above, you need to change it.

Comment: You might also like the [DashboardLayout](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java) that Google used for its iosched app. It uses Buttons by default, but you can basically add any View(Group) to it and it'll nicely space them according to available screen estate.

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` will perfectly fit for you layout.

Change the grid item layout from tutorial and set `android:numColumns="2"` in layout.